# What is the difference between localhost:5000 and other localhosts

Tags: localhost

Could anyone please explain me the difference between `localhost:5000` and other localhosts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

localhost:5000 is accessing localhost on the port 5000.
For example if you access it from a browser, when you request localhost:5000, the browser will go to the webserver on the localhost, but on port 5000, this means that if your webserver is setup to work on port 5000 or one of it's virtual hosts are setup to work on port 5000 you will get a response, otherwise you will get page not found error.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

It is a different port. For example, 80 is usually used as a port for web browsing. For further reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking).